# PLSQL query union sum query

Tags: plsql, union

I need to output running balance in the following query, Please help me with the query-code:

```
select 
 WEAVING_YARN_TR.TR_ID,
 WEAVING_YARN_TR.GP_NO,
 WEAVING_YARN_TR.YR_ID,
 WEAVING_YARN_GATEPASS.TO_FROM as PARTY,
 WEAVING_YARN_GATEPASS.GP_DATE, 
 WEAVING_YARN_TR.BAGS_IN,
 WEAVING_YARN_TR.BAGS_OUT,
 SUM(NVL(WEAVING_YARN_TR.BAGS_OUT,0)-NVL(WEAVING_YARN_TR.BAGS_IN,0)) over (order by GP_DATE)  as BALANCE 
from WEAVING_YARN_TR,WEAVING_YARN_GATEPASS
where WEAVING_YARN_TR.GP_NO=WEAVING_YARN_GATEPASS."GP_NO." and WEAVING_YARN_TR.YR_ID=:P216_YR_ID and WEAVING_YARN_GATEPASS.TO_FROM=:P216_YR_DESC

UNION ALL

select 
 null as TR_ID,
 WEAVING_WARP_SET.SET_ID,
 WEAVING_WARP_SET.YARN_ITEM,
 WEAVING_WARP_SET.PARTY,
 WEAVING_WARP_SET.RECEIVED_DATE,
 WEAVING_WARP_SET.TOTAL_BAGS_CONSUMED,
 null as BAGS_OUT,
NVL(null,0)-NVL(WEAVING_WARP_SET.TOTAL_BAGS_CONSUMED,0) as BALANCE
from WEAVING_WARP_SET
where WEAVING_WARP_SET.YARN_ITEM=:P216_YR_ID and WEAVING_WARP_SET.PARTY= :P216_YR_DESC

order by GP_DATE
```

[image]

Comment: please put your question on sqlfiddle and say what do you want exactly .

Answer (score 0):

So here is the thing; if you're going to use UNION or UNION ALL, each query block has to be the equal column and type.

**For example; We have 2 queries and we want to bind them.**

The first query block contains 3 columns and their type NUMBER, VARCHAR, NUMBER (in order). The second block has to be 3 column and types must be NUMBER, VARCHAR, VARCHAR (in order)

So your query does not seem like that. You want an output like the screenshot that you sent. Here is the query that edited:

```
select 
       weaving_yarn_gatepass.gp_date
      ,weaving_yarn_tr.gp_no
      ,weaving_yarn_gatepass.to_from as party
      ,weaving_yarn_tr.yr_id
      ,weaving_yarn_tr.bags_in
      ,weaving_yarn_tr.bags_out
      ,sum(nvl(weaving_yarn_tr.bags_out,0) - nvl(weaving_yarn_tr.bags_in,0)) over(order by gp_date) as balance
  from weaving_yarn_tr
      ,weaving_yarn_gatepass
 where weaving_yarn_tr.gp_no = WEAVING_YARN_GATEPASS."GP_NO."
   and weaving_yarn_tr.yr_id = :p216_yr_id
   and weaving_yarn_gatepass.to_from = :p216_yr_desc
union all
select 
       weaving_warp_set.received_date  --I don't know if it means gp_date
      ,null as gp_no
      ,weaving_warp_set.party
      ,null yr_id  -- If there is a column named YR_ID in WEAVING_WARP_SET put here
      ,weaving_warp_set.total_bags_consumed
      ,null as bags_out
      ,nvl(null,0) - nvl(weaving_warp_set.total_bags_consumed,0) as balance
  from weaving_warp_set
 where weaving_warp_set.yarn_item = :p216_yr_id
   and weaving_warp_set.party = :p216_yr_desc
 order by gp_date;
```